# How to display model field on html page - Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to display the current lesson amount on the user profile page, but I cannot get it to show up.

Here is my models.py:

```
class LessonCount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    lesson_current_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Current Number of Lessons')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    user = None
    lessoncount = LessonCount.objects.all()
    context = {
        'user': user,
        'lessoncount': lessoncount
    }
    return render(request, 'account/profile.html', context)
```

profile.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h3 style="color: red;">{{ lessoncount.lesson_current_amount }}</h3>

<h3 style="color: red;">{{ request.user.username }}</h3>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through the objects:

```
{% for lesson in lessoncount %}

<h3 style="color: red;">{{ lesson.lesson_current_amount }}</h3>

{% endfor %}
```

Read more about `for` loops [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-for).

Answer (score 3):

You need a `LessonCount` object, but `LessonCount.objects.all()` is a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/).

Change that line to:

```
lessoncount = LessonCount.objects.get(user=request.user)
```